# Simplifying if else statements in Python code snippet

Tags: python, optimization

How can I simplify and optimize this code?

```
if type(variant_list) == dict:
    style_color_if(variant_list[style_colors_main], variant_list)
else:
    for variant in variant_list:
        if type(variant[style_colors_main]) == dict:
            json_key_getter(variant[style_colors_main], variant)
        else:
            for styleColors in variant[style_colors_main]:
                if type(styleColors) == dict:
                    json_key_getter(styleColors, variant)
                else:
                    for styleColor in styleColors:
                        json_key_getter(styleColor, variant)
```

Example of one element of variant list, variant list can have one such thing or many:

http://pastebin.com/axuvzZnh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursion here is going to be your friend:

```
def recurse_json(property, variant):
    # This is our exit condition
    if isinstance(property, dict):
        json_key_getter(property, variant)
    else:
        # Otherwise, WE NEED TO GO DEEPER!
        for item in property:
            recurse_json(item, variant)
```

Now all you have to do is call this function in your for loop:

```
# Use `isinstance` to check for types as it takes inheritance into account.
if isinstance(variant_list, dict):
    style_color_if(variant_list[style_colors_main], variant_list)
else:
    for variant in variant_list:
        try:
            recurse_json(variant[style_colors_main], variant)
        except KeyError:
            print('Property had no "{}" property'.format(style_color_main))
```

I had to put in the try-except blocks because [in your example](http://pastebin.com/axuvzZnh) the first element of the list did not have the `productStyleColors` property (which is what I assume is in `style_color_main`).

The use of `isinstance` isn't ideal because [we would typically like to use try-excepts blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python). However, because I don't know if your other functions throw any exceptions, I chose to use (as the link says) the 'less-bad option'.